# Access Denied when using openJDK

Tags: java

I get an error

> IOException:access denied ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "D:\certainfilelocation" "read")

When accessing a file while using OpenJDK10 instead of JRE. 
I also added in the java.policy this line
*jdk-10.0.2\conf\security*

> permission java.io.FilePermission "<< ALL FILES >>","read";

But I still get the same error.
Is there any way? Thanks

Comment: kindly check the file/folder properties and ensure that `Read` checkbox is enabled

Comment: Are running both the same way (launching from console? (double-)clicking a jar? some kind of IDE?). Have you verified both processes are run by the same user?

Comment: @Arvind Yes. It's already enabled by default

Comment: @Hulk I'm using Eclipse Photon for this. It shows that error when using openJDK10 but if i'm using JRE1.8, it works fine.

Comment: @MelSyGallosa, are you able to view contents of file/folder by your login? Are you using your credentials to run the program?

Comment: @MelSyGallosa please edit this information into your question - might be relevant, especially that you are comparing two _different_ versions of runtime libraries.